# Material Design Template WPF DialogHost wait until close and integration with Prism EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to replace the standard WPF `MessageBox` with a `DialogHost` from `MaterialDesign` Library and I do not know how to wait until the user select's OK or Cancel from the Dialog Box.
The problem I am facing is because I'm calling the display of the dialogue box from a function called using event aggregator.
Below is my code:

```
private async void OnMessageRequest(MessageArgs obj)
{
   MessageDialogModel = _messageDialogCreator();
   MessageDialogModel.Load(obj.Message, obj.HasButtons);
   var view = new SampleDialog
   {
      DataContext = MessageDialogModel
   };

   await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog");

}
```

When I was using `MessageBox` this worked as expected. Here is the code:

```
if (obj.HasButtons)
{
   var result = MessageBox.Show(obj.Message, obj.Title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
   var submitArg = result == MessageBoxResult.OK
      ? MessageDialogResult.OK
      : MessageDialogResult.Cancel;
   _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageDialogResultEvent>().Publish(submitArg);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show(obj.Message, obj.Title);
}
```

Basically what is need is to stop the code after the dialogbox is shown and wait until the user selects and option.
I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to await the result of the `DialogHost.Show` method and handle it, depending on what you pass as `CommandParameter` to the `CloseDialogCommand`. For example, I use a `MessageBoxResult` as command parameter for the buttons in my dialog, to represent OK and cancel.

```
<Button Content="OK"
        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Static MessageBoxResult.OK}"/>
<Button Content="Cancel"
        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Static MessageBoxResult.Cancel}"/>
```

Then in code, I await the result and handle it just like in the code that you have provided.

```
var result = (MessageBoxResult)await DialogHost.Show(msg, "RootDialog");

var submitArg = result == MessageBoxResult.OK
   ? MessageDialogResult.OK
   : MessageDialogResult.Cancel;

_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageDialogResultEvent>().Publish(submitArg);
```

The code after `DialogHost.Show` will be executed after the dialog has been closed.

### Update from comments

Now that you have clarified that you need the method that publishes the event to be waiting, the problem is entirely different.

> What I want to happen is to stop at "result", display the dialog box and wait for the answer. Once the user selects Ok or Cancel carry on with the code.

The `DialogHost` is deliberately built to be used asynchronously. Currently, there is no way to call it synchronously, see [this issue](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1661). In contrast, Prism's event aggregator does not have an asynchronous `Publish` method returning a `Task` or `Task<T>`. Therefore, it cannot be awaited. Moreover, the event aggregator is for *fire and forget* events, so it is by definition not ideal for your current synchronous approach of showing a dialog and I do no think that this is the right approach.

If you want to keep `DialogHost`, return a `Task` from `OnMessageRequest`, to be able to `await` it.

```
private async Task OnMessageRequest(MessageArgs obj)
```

Then you can just await the method to show the dialog and it should work as expected.

```
private async void OnOpenContractorDetailView(int? contractorId)
{
   if (ContractorDetailViewModel != null && ContractorDetailViewModel.HasChanges)
   {
      var messageArgs = new MessageArgs { Message = "You've made changes. Are you sure you want to navigate away?", Title = "Question", HasButtons = true };
      await void OnMessageRequest(messageArgs);

      if (_dialogResult == MessageDialogResult.Cancel)
         return;
   }
   ContractorDetailViewModel = _contractorDetailViewModelCreator();
   await ContractorDetailViewModel.LoadAsync(LoadMenuArgs, contractorId);
}
```

You should consider passing the dialog result from `OnMessageRequest` directly as return value via `Task<MessageDialogResult>`, because using an instance member when dealing with asynchronous methods could lead to data races.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a really nice approach. However, it behaves the same in my structure. I will add a bit more context to the question.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer and your efforts. I did not manage to implement it in this way either. In the end, I had to move on and use the Extended Wpf Toolkit Message Box and I applied some styling there.

Answer (score 0):

The OnMessageRequest is called using the eventaggregator in this function:

```
private async void OnOpenContractorDetailView(int? contractorId)
{
   if (ContractorDetailViewModel != null && ContractorDetailViewModel.HasChanges)
   {
      _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageDialogEvent>()
         .Publish(new MessageArgs { Message = "You've made changes. Are you sure you want to navigate away?", Title = "Question", HasButtons = true });
      if (_dialogResult == MessageDialogResult.Cancel) return;
   }
   ContractorDetailViewModel = _contractorDetailViewModelCreator();
   await ContractorDetailViewModel.LoadAsync(LoadMenuArgs, contractorId);
}
```

When debugging it runs as follows:

1. It hits the _eventAggregator.GetEvent().Publish
2. From there it goes into OnMessageRequest function
3. The OnMessageRequest runs completely
4. Goes back OnOpenContractorDetailView
5. Finishes the method and after that opens the Dialog Box

What I want to happen is to stop at "result", display the dialog box and wait for the answer. Once the user selects Ok or Cancel carry on with the code.

Comment: I have updated my answer to your comments. I hope it helps, although I do not think that the event aggregator is suitable in this scenario, but maybe this solution works for you. As a general note, you should move this context as an edit to your question, because _answers_ are not meant to be _replies_ to posts, that is what comments are for. This helps other people to see your additions. Moreover, if your post gets flagged as _not an answer_ it might be removed.